# System.OutOfMemoryException on Shared Hosting

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting site and on it I have 3 websites hosted. 2 domains and one sub domain.

I am having problems with my sub domain one. Every time I go to it I get

```
'System.OutOfMemoryException' 

Server Error in '/' Application.
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +144
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +618
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +209
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +94
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +332
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256
```

The sites been deployed for a few weeks now am I am the only user using it. No new changes to the code have been done since launched a few weeks ago and when I used the site last week it worked fine.

I tried to reupload all the code but still same problem. Local copy of the codes works fine and no problems.

My other 2 sites are function properly

Comment: Are all of your sites are using the same application pool is it 32 bit or 64 bit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other sites have likely increased their usage to a point where your total memory requirements are bigger then the memory allotted by your hosting company.  Contact them about getting more ram added to your account.

Comment: Ya I emailed them as I can't see anywhere where it says how much memory I have and how much I have used.

Comment: Ya they got back to me and said it was working. Must have been some random thing.

Comment: The problem with it being a random thing is it's likely to happen again.  It's likely that your other sites memory usage changes over time so you'll likely still get the same error in the future (and more often if traffic increases).  It comes down to are you making money from any of these sites OR does it matter in some other way if someone sees this error?  If not.. well just accept it will happen again in the future.  But if it does matter then pay for better hosting either with your current provider or with a new one.

Comment: 2 of the sites I don't make money. One I do make a bit of money. Been using them for a year and half and never seen this happened before. I do have ping checks to that site to check to see if the site is down. I think in the time I been with them, they gone done once when they where hit by a DOS attack. So until it becomes a huge problem and effects the paid site I will leave it.